# ggplot2: Make geom_abline() draw independent slopes and intercepts for each plot of the facet_wrap()

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

Using `geom_abline()`, I was wondering if I could achieve 3 types of face_warpped plots:

First, each plot has an intercept of 12, but slope from topleft to bottom-right start from 1 to 9,

Second, each plot has an slope of 3, but slope from topleft to bottom-right start from 3 to 12,

Third, each plot has a different intercept (from 3 to 12), and different slope from 1 to 9.

Here is what I tried without success:

```
library(ggplot2)

hsb <- read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/hsb.csv')
nine <- subset(hsb, sch.id %in% unique(sch.id)[1:9])

## First (each plot has an intercept of 12, but slope from topleft to bottom-right start from 1 to 9):
ggplot(nine) + aes(ses, math)+ geom_point(size=1) +
  facet_wrap(~sch.id)+geom_abline(intercept = 12,slope = 1:9, col="blue")

## Second (each plot has an slope of 3, but slope from topleft to bottom-right start from 3 to 12):
ggplot(nine) + aes(ses, math)+ geom_point(size=1) +
  facet_wrap(~sch.id)+geom_abline(intercept = 3:12,slope = 3, col="blue")

## Third (each plot has a different intercept (from 3 to 12), and different slope from 1 to 9):
ggplot(nine) + aes(ses, math)+ geom_point(size=1) +
  facet_wrap(~sch.id)+geom_abline(intercept = 3:12,slope = 1:9, col="blue")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with everything else in `ggplot` you want to have a data frame for the ablines and map the intercept and slope with `aes`:

```
library(ggplot2)

hsb <-
  read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/e/master/hsb.csv')
nine <- subset(hsb, sch.id %in% unique(sch.id)[1:9])

slopes_df <- data.frame("sch.id" = unique(nine$sch.id),
                        "interc" = 12,
                        "slopes" = 1:9)

## First (each plot has an intercept of 12, but slope from topleft to bottom-right start from 1 to 9):
ggplot(nine) + aes(ses, math) + geom_point(size = 1) +
  facet_wrap( ~ sch.id) + 
  geom_abline(data = slopes_df, aes(intercept = interc, slope = slopes), col = "blue")
```

Will make this graph:
[image]

Comment: Why doesn't this work if you take out `geom_point()`? The geoms should work independently.